Identify neighbour causing spanning tree to block port on HPE Aruba 2530 (J9773A)
Spanning Tree is blocking one of the ports on one of my Aruba J9773A switches.
How do I discover what port on what device is on the other end of the cable connected to that port?
It's probably one of many other Aruba switches in that location, I would like to know precisely which one.
What I've tried:

List LLDP neighbours/remote-devices on that port: None.
View the MAC address learned on that port: None.
Looked over the spanning tree debug information, and other spanning tree logs: Didn't include what I'm looking for.

Is tracing the physical cable the only way to figure this out?

Without know a lot more about your network, I can't say. In general, ports being blocked are because of the thing directly connected to that port. Start there. (I have a sneaky feeling your network is too big [over 7 hops], but there are things that can "self-loop" traffic - VM's, etc.)

I suspect a rogue root bridge has pulled the root port to an end-node port and any extra VLANs lose connectivity.
I'm afraid to locate that device you'd need to physically follow the cable...

run show spanning-tree detail - check for actually received BPDUs on the relevant port
run show spanning-tree root-history - check for any rogue root bridge
double check the logs (show log | i port) for relevant events
run a debug (debug mstp event & debug destination session) while connecting the suspect port
debug destination buffer allows you to debug for a more extended time period, run show debug buffer on the next day or so

Additionally, there are a number of configuration options preventing any STP abuse, including:

spanning-tree <port> root-guard tcn-guard for end-node ports in general
spanning-tree <port> bpdu-guard for end-node ports to be disabled when a rogue bridge is connected
spanning-tree <port> bpdu-filter for end-node ports that you want to ignore BPDUs on - caution: disables STP and should be combined with loop protection

And of course: choose your root bridge wisely (spanning-tree priority 0), select a backup root bridge (spanning-tree priority 1) and do not accept roots on any other ports (see root-guard above).
If you run multiple MSTP instances, you define your (backup) root for each instance individually.
